# Method call with a handed over function parameter

Tags: python, pyqt, widget, pyqt5

I'm currently working on an UI based on Qt, pyqt and Python as my language. I would like to know if there is any way that I can define a method, which I can hand over a variabel that is later used in a function call. Currently I'm solving it like this:

```
def loader(self, filePath, id):
#firstTable, secondTable and thirdTable are three different Table Widgets in the UI
    if id == "1":
        tab = self.ui.firstTable
    elif id == "2":
        tab = self.ui.secondTable
    elif id == "3":
        tab = self.ui.thirdTable

    tab.clearContents()
    with open(filePath, "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        rowCount = tab.rowCount()
        columnCount = tab.columnCount()
        csvReader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=",", quotechar="'")
        for row in csvReader:
            if csvReader.line_num > rowCount:
                tab.insertRow(csvReader.line_num - 1)
            for i in range(0, columnCount):
                tab.setItem((csvReader.line_num - 1), i, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(row[i]))
    tab.sortItems(1)
```

I want to solve it somewhat like this, but I just don't know how to do it and did not find any solution while researching this problem:

```
def loader(self, filePath, widget):
#variabel widget would be the corresponding object name I want to adress, like firstTable, secondTable, thirdTable
#...
    self.ui.widget.clearContents()
#...
    self.ui.widget.rowCount()
```

I hope I could explain my problem properly and someone can help me with it.
Thank you!

Edit: Here is how I'm currently calling the loader:

```
 self.loader("file.csv", "1")
```

Comment: Can you post the code that will call the loader?  I think this may be easier than you imagine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If widget is a method in some class cl, you can call loader like this:

```
ld = cl.loader(filePath, cl.widget)
```

then where you use it in loader:

```
widget.clearcontents(self)
```

etc.

Remember that a method is just a function with an implied first parameter -- the class reference.

Comment: Thanks so much! Now it is working, I don't know what I was thinking before